# Call web service from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services

I had used this query to call web Service in local system .. by I am getting response as "NULL"

The web service is working fine ....

```
  DECLARE @obj INT
  DECLARE @sUrl VARCHAR(200)
  DECLARE @response VARCHAR(8000)

  SET @sUrl = 'http://localhost/MyWorks/SampleWebService.asmx/HelloWorld'
  EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj,'Open',NULL,'GET',@sUrl,false
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj,'send'
  EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj,'responseText',@response OUT
  SELECT @response [response]
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

Web service code:

```
 public class SampleWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {    
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rajeevConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employees set FirstName = 'Jhon' where ID=7", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            return "Updated";
            //sending the mail code.
        }
    }
```

Comment: try providing **port no** instead of Local Host.

Comment: ya i have tried that tooo.